# "OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory" when running storm 0.9.6

Tags: netty, apache-storm

I ran a simple wordcount topology on storm0.9.6, found 2 abnormal behaviors

1. Netty reconnect so many time.
2. direct memory continuously growing. and finally throw java.lang.OutOfMemoryError.

following is the unexpected information:

```
2015-12-15T21:30:18.546+0800 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Activating spout emitSpout:(1)
2015-12-15T21:30:18.578+0800 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Preparing bolt __system:(-1)
2015-12-15T21:30:18.614+0800 b.s.d.executor [INFO] Prepared bolt __system:(-1)
2015-12-15T21:38:37.453+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 943 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
2015-12-15T21:38:37.457+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 944 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.464+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 945 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.472+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 944 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.477+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 943 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.479+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 938 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.481+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 946 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.482+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 943 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.484+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 943 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.485+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 941 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.490+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 942 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.504+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 941 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.505+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 943 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.507+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 944 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.510+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 944 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.516+0800 b.s.m.n.StormClientHandler [INFO] Connection failed Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
    at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:658) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:306) ~[na:1.7.0_67]
    at org.apache.storm.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers.directBuffer(ChannelBuffers.java:167) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at org.apache.storm.netty.buffer.ChannelBuffers.directBuffer(ChannelBuffers.java:151) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.MessageBatch.buffer(MessageBatch.java:84) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.MessageEncoder.encode(MessageEncoder.java:32) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at org.apache.storm.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.doEncode(OneToOneEncoder.java:66) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at org.apache.storm.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:59) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at org.apache.storm.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:591) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at org.apache.storm.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendDownstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:582) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at org.apache.storm.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:704) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at org.apache.storm.netty.channel.Channels.write(Channels.java:671) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at org.apache.storm.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.write(AbstractChannel.java:248) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Client.flushMessages(Client.java:323) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Client.send(Client.java:250) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.utils.TransferDrainer.send(TransferDrainer.java:54) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$mk_transfer_tuples_handler$fn__4610$fn__4611.invoke(worker.clj:338) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$mk_transfer_tuples_handler$fn__4610.invoke(worker.clj:336) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$clojure_handler$reify__1445.onEvent(disruptor.clj:58) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchToCursor(DisruptorQueue.java:132) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.utils.DisruptorQueue.consumeBatchWhenAvailable(DisruptorQueue.java:106) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_batch_when_available.invoke(disruptor.clj:80) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.disruptor$consume_loop_STAR_$fn__1458.invoke(disruptor.clj:94) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__460.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.6.jar:0.9.6]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
2015-12-15T21:38:37.516+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 945 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2015-12-15T21:38:37.521+0800 b.s.m.n.Client [ERROR] failed to send 944 messages to Netty-Client-eda.local/192.168.137.2:6708: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
```

and my configure Fragment in storm.yaml as following:

```
#topology.skip.missing.kryo.registrations: false
storm.messaging.netty.flush.check.interval.ms: 100
storm.messaging.transport: "backtype.storm.messaging.netty.Context"
storm.messaging.netty.server_worker_threads: 1
storm.messaging.netty.client_worker_threads: 1
#storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size: 5242880
storm.messaging.netty.transfer.batch.size: 462144
storm.messaging.netty.buffer_size: 5242880
storm.messaging.netty.max_retries: 100
storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms: 1000
storm.messaging.netty.min_wait_ms: 100
topology.backpressure.enable: false
#storm.scheduler: "backtype.storm.scheduler.DefaultScheduler"
worker.childopts: "-Xmx768m -XX:NewSize=128m -XX:MaxNewSize=128m -XX:PermSize=64m -XX:MaxPermSize=64m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=128m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true  -XX:+UseParNewGC  -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/ffcs/gc/gc-storm-worker-%ID%.log -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/ffcs/gc/heapdump"
#worker.childopts: "-Xmx1024m"
supervisor.childopts: "-Xmx256m"
nimbus.childopts: "-Xmx768m"
ui.childopts: "-Xmx768m"
nimbus.thrift.threads: 256
```

Anyone knows how to solve these 2 problems?

Comment: About the growing memory: looks like you have a bottleneck in the topology (ie, to small dop of a consuming operator) and you do not use acking for flow control. So either try to increase the parallelism is the bottleneck operator or use acking for flow control (parameter `MAX_SPOUT_PENDING`). For Netty: What do you mean by "connects so many times"? At startup for examples it take some time until a connection can be established as all worker node must start up first. As you topology runs, I am not sure if there is really a problem -- right nowI doubt it. Do you have any error logs about it?

Comment: About the growing memory, I have increased the parallelism of the bottleneck operator, it works.
For the problem about netty reconnect when storm runs, it seems like a bug of netty. 
I have increased the value of storm.messaging.netty.max_wait_ms, the situation has improved.

Comment: Great! Not sure if the netty reconnect is a bug or not thought. Setting up network connections just takes some time. When you submit a topology, new worker JVM are started on different machines, which is of course a asynchronous operation. Thus, if the first JVM is up and tries to connect via Netty to another worker, this worker JVM might not be ready and thus you see those log messages until the second worker JVM is ready to accept an network request.